# Does AMDGPU on Ubuntu 16.04 supports Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

My laptop has **Dual GPU** integrated.

1. *Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller*
2. *Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]*

Now, while testing Ubuntu 16.04 using Live USB, I could not confirm as if the **AMDGPU** was *installed or not, or even either supported or not*.

**Does AMDGPU supports the Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series on Ubuntu 16.04, or not, or not yet?**

- If *does* support, how can I verify or install  the AMDGPU (as I read, it should be auto installed, isn't it?)? (*please don't confuse the Live USB scenario, that was just for checking, due to the news about amdgpu and ubuntu 16.04. i am asking for the actual full/hard install into the device, here in case my laptop*)
- If *does not* support, can I hope for it to be supported?
- If *not yet* supported, can I hope for it to be supported?
- If *will not* be supported, well that's a misery, I guess!

I have looked into the [RadeonDriver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) page from Ubuntu, but could not locate my GPU neither as supported nor unsupported.

**Some Related Information:**

> *lspci -nn | grep VGA*

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff)
```

> *lspci -v -s 00:02.0*

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f6800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

> *lspci -v -s 01:00.0*

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lspci -v -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

*Thanks :)*

Answer (score 3):

This adapter is not supported by `amdgpu`. It is supported by `radeon` as you see in the output.

It is extremely unlikely that older GPUs will be ever supported by `amdgpu`.

`radeon` driver will be supported and I do not see what is the problem.

Comment: is not "radeon" driver the "fglrx" one? and as I see, the "fglrx" is deprecated from ubuntu 16.04. that's why the question of supported gpu by "amdgpu" appear.

Comment: `radeon` is not `fglrx`.