# Is Radeon HD 6970M supported on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have a laptop with a AMD Radeon HD 6970M (note the M! this is a mobile GPU!). I upgraded a working Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 and now have a login loop due to no driver listing this GPU as being supported. I have learned that `fglrx` was dropped in 16.04, but other questions such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803005/does-amdgpu-on-ubuntu-16-04-supports-radeon-hd-6400m-7400m-series) seem to indicate that 6400M+ should work with the `radeon` driver. I already tried to use Oibaf's drivers as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics) to no avail.

`lshw -c video` and similar commands do not mention a driver, and `ubuntu-drivers devices` does not even mention my GPU.

Is the Radeon HD 6970M supported in Ubuntu 16.04? Is there a way to force the `radeon` driver to work with it?

Edit: The HD 6970M chip is based on the desktop HD 6850, which `radeon` lists as a supported GPU. It more or less doesn't mention mobile GPUs so their support status is unclear. I have [filed a bug to the xorg `radeon` driver maintainers](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100743).

Comment: When you tried the Oibaf's drivers, did you actually install a driver?  Because according to the instructions, you just add the repository, then run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`.  I have an older laptop using the Mobility Radeon HD 4530, and my tests show that the driver did load.

Comment: Yep, installed the drivers, rebooted, but still no supporting drivers detected.